# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\log_2 x}}{(\log_2 x)^x}$

Tags: limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\log_2 x}}{(\log_2 x)^x}$$
I tried to evaluate this limit by taking natural log and using L'Hospital rule. However, it seems that both methods make the expression even harder to evaluate. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Observe that $\log_2 x$ grows slower than $x$, and your limit is in the form $\dfrac {m^n}{n^m}$.

Comment: it is  will be $0$

Comment: Try $x=2^k,k\to \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{x^{\log_2 x}}{(\log_2 x)^x}=2^{(\log_2 x)^2-x\log_2(\log_2 x)}$$

and

$$(\log_2 x)^2-x\log_2(\log_2 x)=x\left(\frac{(\log_2 x)^2}x-\log_2(\log_2 x)\right)\to -\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Introduce $u=\log_2x$ i.e. $x=2^u$. Your limit becomes:

$$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{(2^u)^u}{u^{(2^u)}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{2^{(u^2)}}{u^{(2^u)}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{2^{(u^2)}}{u^{(u^2)}}\cdot\frac{1}{u^{(2^u-u^2)}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{u}\right)^{u^2}\cdot\frac{1}{u^{(2^u-u^2)}}=0\cdot0=0$$